# How do I detect and sum from a .csv file?

Tags: r, csv, sum, read.csv

I'm trying to learn how to code in R for university but I'm stuck, so I will be glad if could help me.
I have a .csv file imported in R, as shown in the image, and I need to sum from Pre1 to Pre14 every data contained from row 1 to 34. I already knew that doing `sum1=sum(table[1,3]+table[1,4]+..)` I will sum every data selected, but there should be something better than that.
I'd also like to know if I can select specific data, let's say from pre1 to pre7, only male subjects, and sum them.

Thanks in advance!
[image: image of the table from imported .csv in R]

Comment: With the `[` operator you can subset your data.frame. For instance `df[,3:7]` will select columns 3 to 7. Then, you can use `rowSums` to get the sum of each row. Also with the `[` operator you can subset rows; for instance `df[df$Sesso=="M",]` will give you only the rows with `Sesso=="M"`.

Comment: If you want to select only the columns that start with "pre", for instance, you can do something like `df[, startsWith(colnames(df), "pre")]`

Comment: Hi Stefano, in order to make it easier for other it would be good to include a [reproducible example](https://github.com/tidyverse/reprex). It will definitely increase your chances to get an answer.